# Modify the product price in minicart

Tags: magento2, price, phtml, html, mini-cart

I try to change  the price from minicart with a custom product attribute, but in `C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html` the price is render like this:

```
<div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                           maxlength="12"/>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and then in `C:\xampp2\htdocs\myproject\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\price.html`

```
<div class="price-container">
  <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: price"></span>

</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to change the default price with a custom attribute?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Custom  cart price, you need to create the **Observer** and **override the event** name called **checkout_cart_product_add_after**

Answer (score 0):

Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php call for top cart

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
        return [
            'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),
            'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
                ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
                : 0,
            'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
            'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
            'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
            'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        ];
    }
```

In that section it will call getRecentItems(), it will call Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem.php ( based on product type)

```
protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }
```

where you can find product price,you need to replace it.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @Alin is that works?

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339803/57334 @Snil