# How to customize update Mini-cart individual product price total when qty increased - KnockoutJS

Tags: price, knockoutjs, magento2.4.1, qty-increment, magento2minicart

I want to increase product price when to increase qty in Minicart, but here order total increased but price not updated.

[image]

Comment: Please add some code here, which you used.

Comment: What approach should i follow, i need some guidance.

Comment: Please try this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262976/how-to-add-quantity-increment-and-decreament-and-button-in-minicart-magent

Comment: I did increment and decrement button, i need to update price also.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link .....
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czt4WvHILa4